# How do I map a List<String> from JSON to JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a List that I want to store in the DB as a JSON string array. I've tried various ways of doing it but just can't get it working.

The column is currently defined as:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR(4000)")
@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
@Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
protected List<String> tagsT = new ArrayList<>();
```

When I try build this I get a mapping exception of "Could not determine type for: java.util.List".

Alternatively I've also tried defining the column as:

```
@Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
protected ArrayList<String> tagsT = new ArrayList<>();
```

This builds successfully, however it generates a varbinary column which is not what I'm looking for. If I manually change the column to a NVARCHAR(4000) or a VARCHAR(255) then the data written still doesn't make sense.

I've also tried:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR(4000)")
@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
@Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
protected ArrayList<String> tagsT = new ArrayList<>();
```

But got the same results as previously.

Any help would be appreciated as to what I'm doing wrong/missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how is your StringListConverter looks like?

here is working example for Map, but you can adjust it for your case if you change type reference to List

```
  @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
  @Convert(converter = JsonConverter.class)
  private Map<String, String> connectParameters;
```

```
@Converter
public class JsonConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, String>, String> {

  private final static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  private final TypeReference<Map<String, String>> mapTypeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
  };

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, String> data) {

    if (null == data) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
      log.error("Couldn't convert data-map to JSON String.", ex);
      return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {

    if (null == dbData || dbData.isEmpty()) {
      return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    try {
      return objectMapper.readValue(dbData, mapTypeRef);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      log.error("Couldn't convert JSON String to data-map.", ex);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried copying this exactly and changing any use of Map<String, String> to ArrayList<String> but I still get the same issue of it generating a varbinary(255) column in the database..

Comment: if you want it to be stored as json type in database you should change type of the column to json if it is supported by your database (via ALTER TABLE). @Converter just taking string from table and via objectMapper translates it to Map or List or whatever structure you want to see in your java classes and if it needs to be stored in database table it converts it back to string and then that string is stored as char/varchar/text/json depends on column type in your database table.

Comment: Yeah so I'm using SQL Server which according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#combine-relational-and-json-data) I've to just store it in a VARCHAR or NVARCHAR column as text. Which is why I've just kept the @Converter converting to String for convertToDatabaseColumn. If I create an arraylist and add "Tag 1" to it and save it, the value in the database is "¬í"

Comment: Well, that is very strange. Can you check if you use UTF-8 in java and DB? And also that `convertToDatabaseColumn` returns you a normal readable string.

Comment: So I finally have it working. I tried logging from inside the convertToDatabaseColumn to show it was being called and it wasn't ever being called. I tried adding the class to the persistence.xml which also made no difference. I then tried setting autoApply to true on the converter and now it seems to work. Bit annoying that using @Convert doesn't seem to work but this will do fine. Thanks for the help 